# How do i create this graph on latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-trees, tikz-styles

So…i made this graph using paint(!)…and it looks horrible. I have used tikz to create similar graphs but this one seems to be more difficult. [image: Figure1]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: yes you're right it was to good to be true….

Comment: Do you have any particular aversion to using a vector graphics editor such as [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) to create the diagram, exporting to EPS or PDF, and indluding it via `\includegraphics` or some similar?  That would be my first approach, personally.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one approach. Most parts are straightforward TikZ syntax. The somewhat unique parts of this drawing are the multipart nodes and the smooth curves, which I'll explain a bit more in this answer.

For the multipart nodes, I defined a style `mysplit` that's applied to each node we want to split. This avoids repeating yourself and ensures consistency in your drawing. The first node text is placed in the `one` subpart of the node, and following `\nodepart{<part>}` following text is placed in the `<part>` subpart of the node. Then later on we can refer to anchors of each specific subpart (the last two `\draw` commands).

Some people find the `.. controls ..` interface for creating Bézier curves too verbose for some curves (myself included). Here, I use `to` paths instead. Each part of the `to` path takes `in` and `out` parameters: the incoming and outgoing angle of the curve. These angles can be varied to produce different curves. The `looseness` parameter (default 1.0) is also adjustable.

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{mysplit/.style={%
  draw,
  anchor=text,
  rectangle split,
  rectangle split horizontal,
  rectangle split parts=2,
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=left]
  \draw[looseness=0.7] (0.5,2.8) coordinate (OutMoney)
    to[out=-45,in=180] (3,1.5) coordinate (AtMoney)
    to[out=0,in=210] coordinate[pos=0.75] (InMoney) (6,2.8);
  \draw[dashed] (OutMoney) |- (3,0) -| (InMoney);
  \draw (AtMoney) -- (3,0) node[midway,fill=white] {At the money};
  \draw[thick] (0,3) node[below left] {Implied\\volatility} 
    |- (6,0) node[below] {Strike};
  \node[mysplit] (Out) at (-1.5,-2) {Out of the\\money\\put 
                                      \nodepart{two} 
                                     In the\\money\\call};
  \node[mysplit] (In)  at ( 4.5,-2) {In the\\money\\put 
                                      \nodepart{two} 
                                     Out of the\\money\\call};
  \draw (Out.one north) to[out=90,in=210] (1.25,1.5);
  \draw  (In.one north) to[out=90,in=-30] (4.25,1.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]